# boto3 Deleting ec2 Snapshots out of List

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto3, snapshot

I'm creating a python list where snapshots ID's are stored that dont have a specific tag. Is it possible to delete all those Snapshots inside the list automaticlly?

```
for snapshot in snapshots.filter(OwnerIds=['self']):

    # checking if PSP is set
    if (not costreferencetag_isset_snapshot(snapshot)):

        tag_snapshot = str(snapshot.id)
        Snapshot_ID.append(tag_snapshot)

        continue
    else:
        costreference_snapshot = get_costreference_snapshot(snapshot)

        if costreference_snapshot not in managedpsp:

            tag_snapshot = str(snapshot.id)
            Snapshot_ID.append(tag_snapshot)
ec2.delete_snapshot(Snapshot_ID)
```

The deletion-process should happen in the last line of the code example. 
I cant really test it right now because this would delete Snapshots I still have to use at the moment.

The list is `Snapshot_ID` and stores only the right Snapshot that I want to delete.

Can anyone confirm that this will work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`delete_snapshot()`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Client.delete_snapshot) method accepts only one Snapshot ID.

You have to either loop it through the list of Snapshot IDs

```
for s in Snapshot_ID:
   ec2.delete_snapshot(SnapshotId=s)
```

Or delete them in place of appending them to the list

```
for snapshot in snapshots.filter(OwnerIds=['self']):

    # checking if PSP is set
    if (not costreferencetag_isset_snapshot(snapshot)):

        tag_snapshot = str(snapshot.id)
        ec2.delete_snapshot(SnapshotId=tag_snapshot)

        continue
    else:
        costreference_snapshot = get_costreference_snapshot(snapshot)

        if costreference_snapshot not in managedpsp:

            tag_snapshot = str(snapshot.id)
            ec2.delete_snapshot(SnapshotId=tag_snapshot)
```

**Note:** You can specify `DryRun=True` to verify whether it works without actually deleting the snapshots.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! Could I also implement `ec2.snapshot.delete()` in the for-loop? So that he deletes every valid snapshot in every repitition of the loop? So this would be basically what you said...

Comment: Yes. You can delete the snapshot in the main for loop also, replace `Snapshot_ID.append(tag_snapshot)` with `ec2.delete_snapshot(SnapshotId=tag_snapshot)`.

Comment: `for snapshot in snapshots.filter(OwnerIds=['self']):
if (not costreferencetag_isset_snapshot(snapshot)):
      ec2.snapshot.delete()
      continue
else:
      costreference_snapshot = get_costreference_snapshot(snapshot)
      if costreference_snapshot not in managedpsp:
      ec2.snapshot.delete()`
So like this?